# How can I tell Perl XML::LibXML to use newer libxml2 library during runtime?

Tags: perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

Our machines come with `libxml2 2.7.6` pre-installed on them. However, someone needed a newer version of `libxml2` and installed `2.7.8` on our networked file system. Likewise, they used this version of `libxml2` to compile their version of the Perl module `XML::LibXML`, a Perl interface for `libxml2`. This was also placed on the network drive and is meant for developer use.

I am currently trying to use their compiled version of `XML::LibXML`. My script finds the module just fine, but when it goes to run it, it complains that it was compiled against a newer version of `libxml2` than the one the script is looking at:

```
Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20708, but runtime libxml2 is older 20706
```

Obviously the Perl script is still looking at the system's `libxml2`, but I need it to use the newer version. Rather than recompiling the `XML::LibXML` module against the old `libxml2` library again, is there any way I can tell Perl to simply use the newer `libxml2` library?

Comment: Thanks to show us your code. Maybe you just have to modify `@INC`

Answer (score 1):

One solution :

```
BEGIN{ @INC = ( "/SPECIAL/PERL/MODULES/DEV/PATH", @INC );
```

The string

```
/SPECIAL/PERL/MODULES/DEV/PATH
```

is the PATH before

```
/SPECIAL/PERL/COMPILED/MODULES/DEV/PATH/XML/LibXML.pm
```

---

If instead the problem is the library PATH (`*.so`), then you should modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` :

```
BEGIN{ $ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} = "/SPECIAL/SYSTEM/MODULES/DEV/PATH"; }
```

Comment: It can find LibXML.pm just fine, though. The issue is that its looking at the system's old libxml2 library, whereas I need it to look at our newer libxml2 library.